# Spring Adotemplate.commandtimeout

Tags: spring.net

I am using Spring.NET framework in an ASP.NET MVC project to query sql server databases.
There is a commandtimeout property in Adotemplate class & i would like to know if this is in seconds or minutes?

ex:

```
using spring.data.core;
using spring.data.common;

adotemplate.commandtimeout = 30;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command timeout property is in Seconds

Comment: can you point me towards any documentation mentioning the above? I couldn't find any even with google.

Comment: 20.6.5. Quick Guide to AdoTemplate Properties
It explicitly says that is sets the CommandTimeout property of the IdbCommand that the template will execute. That property is an int and the values are in seconds. Are you experiencing some problem that makes you think that this is not so?